# Check if any object in a 2d array is null

Tags: c#, linq, syntax

I've got an array `var cells = new Cell[w, h]`, can I loop through all cells without a nested for-loop (I want to check if at least one is null)? Ideally I'd want to write something like `Debug.Assert(!cells.Contains(null))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

foreach loop ?

```
foreach (var item in cells)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: +1 I think this is the easiest way of doing it out of the box.

Comment: Thanks. Also I just found another way: `Debug.Assert(!cells.Cast<Cell>().Contains(null))`. I wonder why the "Cast" is needed. An "AsEnumerable" or "Flattened" function would have been more intuitive.